# How to ping ip in js or node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, ip, ping

I create electron app which check availability of ip. To check availability you should ping ip. I use fetch api and with domens it work all right, but if i try to ping ip in local network like 192.168.1.190 i getting rejecting, but if i ping it by `cmd` ping it getting me successful result. I found library `ping` but it working like fetch and getting rejecting local ips. How should i ping?

P.S

ip like 8.8.8.8 also return rejecting in fetch api, but in cmd ping all right.

Comment: Try searching for a node ICMP module

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you use nodejs, you could use exec to call system ping command.

```
const exec = require('child_process').exec;
function process(error, stdout, stderr) {
    //TODO: process result or logging.
}
exec("ping -c 3 localhost", process);
```

Or you can use 3rd party libraries.
https://github.com/nospaceships/node-net-ping

Answer (score 3):

Using [`icmp`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/icmp) package:

```js
const icmp = require('icmp');

icmp.send('8.8.8.8', "Hey, I'm sending a message!")
    .then(obj => {
        console.log(obj.open ? 'Done' : 'Failed')
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Comment: icmp have dependency `row-socket`, electron can't successful compile it